# How to do users Load testing of mobile app?

Tags: automated-testing, load-testing, mobile

I don't have source code of application, I just downloaded an application from play store.

Is there any way to do load testing of users.

My scenario is 100,000 users using the App simultaneously.

Comment: What do you mean load testing the *app*? The local app on the phone is only going to have ~1 user at a time, do you mean load testing of the services (if any) that the app communicates with?

Comment: I mean I don't have a source code of app, means I don't know that what's the url of APIs and server. In that case, Is there any tool which is providing an environment to test app with multiple users?

I need to test the app that 100,000 users logged in at a time and app still working fine. if yes than increase the no. of logged in users to check when app will starting to crash.

Comment: Why don't you ask where those services are? Or if you're just randomly testing the app without any connection to the people who made it, then... why?

Comment: team has left and not providing anything and app is live now. just confirming that is there any way to test the app.

Comment: In that case is it a good idea to be doing this at all? Think this through; if you knock it over, *what are you going to do about it*? This is less of a test and more of a potential DDoS.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to load test the [backend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_end_and_back_end#Back-end_focused) of the mobile application you need to simulate the application's network traffic, to wit:

1. Capture the network calls which are being made by the application
2. Use JMeter [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) or [Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) to mimic it from JMeter
3. Add 100 000 virtual users in the Thread Group (at this stage most probably you will have to go for [Distributed Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter/))

If the application uses [HTTP protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) for communicating with the backend you can even record its network activity using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), you will need to [configure your device to use JMeter as the proxy](https://www.howtogeek.com/295048/how-to-configure-a-proxy-server-on-android/)